# why does only the 1st file reading function executes over multiple programs of the same kind in C language?

Tags: c, file-handling, fgetc

This code contains 3 file handling related functions which read from a file named "mno". But only the 1st called function in the main() is working. If the 1st function of the list is commented then, only the 2nd function will work and the third won't. Same goes for the 3rd one

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void countVowel(char fin[])
{
  FILE *fl;
  char ch;
  int count = 0;
  fl = fopen(fin, "r");
  while (ch != EOF)
  {
    ch = tolower(fgetc(fl));
    count += (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') ? 1 : 0;
  }
  fclose(fl);
  printf("Number of Vowels in the file \" %s \"-> \t %d \n", fin, count);
}

void countConsonant(char fin[])
{
  FILE *fl;
  char ch;
  int count = 0;
  fl = fopen(fin, "r");
  while (ch != EOF)
  {
    ch = tolower(fgetc(fl));
    count += (!(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') && (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  fclose(fl);
  printf("Number of Consonant in the file \" %s \"-> \t %d \n", fin, count);
}

void countAlphabet(char fin[])
{
  FILE *fl;
  char ch;
  int count = 0;
  fl = fopen(fin, "r");
  while (ch != EOF)
  {
    ch = tolower(fgetc(fl));
    count += (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ? 1 : 0;
  }
  fclose(fl);
  printf("Number of Alphabets in the file \" %s \"-> \t %d \n", fin, count);
}

int main()
{
  countVowel("mno"); // output -> 10
  countConsonant("mno"); // output -> 0
  countAlphabet("mno"); // output -> 0
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the contents of "mno" file ->

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm, QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM, 1234567890
```

Comment: `ch` is uninitialized in all of the functions so it's value is indeterminate. It could be `EOF`, especially since it's going to be whatever was leftover on the stack. You should initialize it to something else. You should also restructure your loop to not use the value before checking if it is `EOF`. Like here: `ch = tolower(fgetc(fl));` if `fgetc` returns `EOF` you handle it as if the read was successful.

Comment: You forgot to enable compiler warnings and fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ch` uninitialized. at `while (ch != EOF)`. Every function call after the first has `ch` equal to 0 at the start, because you forgot to initialize it and the memory was set to -1 before. You can fix it by replacing the loops like this:

```
int ch;
...
while ((ch = fgetc(fl)) != EOF)
{
    ch = tolower(ch);
    count += ...;
}
```

Here `ch` is getting initialized before you check it and later converted to lowercase.

EDIT:

Note that this only works if `ch` is an int, so it can handle the value of -1 (EOF) and the byte 255 is not truncated to -1.

EDIT:

At first I said `ch` was 0 all the time. It was -1. I am so sorry, I swapped it with the null terminator, which is usually the reason for such behavior.

Comment: "Every function call after the first has ch equal to 0 at the start" is not true, and `EOF != 9`.

Comment: It is uninitialized and in his case it started as 0. And why would EOF be 9?

Comment: uninitialized variables with local storage duration are not initialized with 0. Using them yields Undefined Behavior. It is wrong to say `ch` is initialized with `0`

Comment: @bolov Yes, I know, but in his case they were 0. This is because `ch` used the same registers in every call and was never overwritten. So the register storing `ch` was always 0 after the first call.

Comment: Typo, `EOF != 0`.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem, ch is -1 in his, case. I am so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 128 as a signed char would be -128, 255 would be -1. `char` can also be signed or unsigned.

Comment: Sorry my bad, ch = 255 would be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your handling of `EOF` was incorrect:

1. `ch` was uninitialized on the first loop iteration
2. Doing `tolower(fgetc(fl))` would obliterate the `EOF` value.
3. Using `char ch;` instead of `int ch;` would allow a [legitimate] 0xFF to be seen as an EOF.

But, it seems wasteful to have three separate functions to create the three different counts because the most time is spent in the I/O versus the determination of what type of character we're looking at. This is particularly true when the counts are so interelated.

We can keep track of multiple types of counts easily using a `struct`.

Here's a refactored version that calculates all three counts in a *single* pass through the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct counts {
    int vowels;
    int consonants;
    int alpha;
};

void
countAll(const char *fin,struct counts *count)
{
    FILE *fl;
    int ch;
    int vowel;

    count->vowels = 0;
    count->consonants = 0;
    count->alpha = 0;

    fl = fopen(fin, "r");

    if (fl == NULL) {
        perror(fin);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(fl);

        // stop on EOF
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;

        // we only care about alphabetic chars
        if (! isalpha(ch))
            continue;

        // got one more ...
        count->alpha += 1;

        ch = tolower(ch);

        // is current character a vowel?
        vowel = (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u');

        // since we know it's alphabetic, it _must_ be either a vowel or a
        // consonant
        if (vowel)
            count->vowels += 1;
        else
            count->consonants += 1;
    }

    fclose(fl);

    printf("In the file: \"%s\"\n",fin);
    printf("  Number of Vowels: %d\n",count->vowels);
    printf("  Number of Consonants: %d\n",count->consonants);
    printf("  Number of Alphabetics: %d\n",count->alpha);
}

int
main(void)
{

    struct counts count;
    countAll("mno",&count);

    return 0;
}
```

---

For your given input file, the program output is:

```
In the file: "mno"
  Number of Vowels: 10
  Number of Consonants: 42
  Number of Alphabetics: 52
```